# Googlescript and AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to interact with Amazon Web Services DynamoDB in a Google Sheet via code in a GoogleScript. However, I cannot figure out how to integrate the AWS SDK. I am hoping to avoid having to write a library to handle the integration via the AWS HTTP API, as there are JavaScript and Java SDKs available for the SDK. Help?

(I've done some pretty extensive Google and Stack Overflow searches.  [This](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/620) is the closest thing I've found to an answer, but that is the Google App Engine, not the Google Apps Script.)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see the part at that page you linked, where they said "GAS has no native support for XHR, which is integral to the correct functioning of the SDK"? It sounds like it isn't going to work. AWS has an SDK for JavaScript within a browser, and for JavaScript in a NodeJS environment. I don't think either of those are going to work inside a Google Script environment. Also not sure why you point out that there is a Java SDK, which is completely irrelevant when working with JavaScript, unless you mistakenly think Java and JavaScript are somehow related.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm very new to GoogleScript, and wasn't sure if the existence of the Java SDK would be relevant so I included it. That particular respondent does state that GAS has no support for XHR, but the Google Apps Script team introduced their IFRAME sandboxing, which makes me think that there is a way to make XHR calls [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) and [here](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html). I might be completely misunderstanding the framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just made a function that does the basic authentication for any api request you want to make. You still might have to get some of the headers in order but it does most of the hard work for you.

For example:

```
function myFunction() {
  AWS.init("MY_ACCESS_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY");
  var instanceXML = AWS.request('ec2', 'us-east-1', 'DescribeInstances', {"Version":"2015-10-01"});
  ...
}
```

I put it in a repo with some documentation for use. Here's the link: https://github.com/smithy545/aws-apps-scripts

Comment: Hi. Can you confirm that you aws.js code is not covering the case where the parameters to a call are themselves an object. it would seem to me that an encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify()) call is needed to be able to pass json objects on GET requests....

Comment: @user2123288 well that's usually when you would use a post request and pass the params as a json string payload

Comment: Note that for certain services, headers might need to change. For instance, getting Comprehend to work required changing X-Amz-Target to a different action format, e.g. "Comprehend_20171127.DetectSentiment", and Content-type had to be "application/x-amz-json-1.1". (Otherwise got errors like "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized".)

Answer (score 7):

I recently added my own derivative of the "AWS via Google Apps Script" here: https://github.com/neilobremski/gas/blob/main/GasAWS.js

The JavaScript code here is a bit more modern and specifically uses the [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) available in Google Apps Script for the SHA-256 stuff rather than the abandoned (but excellent!) [Crypto-JS](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) library.

Usage is the same *except* I moved the `region` parameter and have a global default. I did this because often resources are in the same region and repeatedly specifying it is a pain.

Comment: The most comprehensive answer I have ever seen.

Comment: Neil do you possibly have an example where you are able to query lambda and return the function name, description, and runtime as well as other attributes?  This is great though thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Responding if anyone else finds this useful, one of the responses above gave a good hint for me to get started but not able to add comment on it.

Steps in below tutorial walks through setting up API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDb. Once setup, you can directly use URLFetch in GAS to your API Gateway.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html

Code in AWS link is complete and needs no additional setup to work directly using URL Fetch. You may however want to enable security on API Gateway.

On GAS side -

```
var headers = {
  "x-api-key" : AWS_KEY
};    

var event = {};
event.operation = "create";
event.tableName = AWS_DB_NAME;
event.payload.Item = yourDataObjwithKey;

var options = {
  "method":"POST",
  "headers":headers,
  "payload":JSON.stringify(event)
};    

var url = AWS_GW;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am about to implement this and it looks like the best way is to use a Lambda function to query the DynamoDB via API Gateway.

It's really not that hard if you know NodeJS.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, I'm not sure how valuable it is to point out something isn't that hard to do if you already know how to do it.  I'm pretty sure the point of this website is to share how to do things.

Comment: If you let me know what kind of interaction between the two you want, I can post some example code in NodeJS and tell you how it works. 

In short, you need a NodeJS script that interacts with the DynamoDB, then upload that into Lambda. 

Finally, an API gateway that invokes the Lambda function.

Comment: yeah, the question is about setting up API Gateway access in the Apps Script environment, not whether or not going through severless-Lambda or direct to the db is better..... unless it is possible to make properly secured requests easier this way, i.e. - it's a different API