# How to send email via AWS SES from Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-ses

I have a AWS SES User credentials and I want to send an email with an attached pdf via this user in Google AppScript. Unfortunately the AWS SDK for nodejs does not work in AppScript which leaves me with two options.

1. [Using the SMTP Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-smtp.html)
2. Make a direct HTTP request using [the REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/Welcome.html)

I could not find a way to send a SMTP request from AppScript which leaves only option 2.
However I could not find any code example where this one was achieved. The [SendMail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_SendEmail.html) Action describes the request but there is not field where I could put in the attachment. Does this mean I have to use the RAW type and create a MIME-formatted email to add an attachment?

I also don't understand the needed Parameter, how the [signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/CommonParameters.html) is created from the SES user I have and so on, do I even need AWS credentials?

I am quite lost, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've had success using the script by smith545 that David Salomon links below, to send SMS.  For email, you would do `AWS.init(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)` followed by something like `AWS.request('ses', 'us-west-2', 'SendEmail', payload)`, where `payload` is an object like the one in the "Request Syntax" section of the SendEmail documentation you linked.  But I'm not sure how you'd do the attachment.  It looks like you need to use the `Raw` option, but the documentation is sparse on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do it. Two alternatives:

### 1. Create your own AWS library

To do that, as you mentioned, you need to use the REST API and create some functions to call it. You can use JavaScript and you can deploy it on your Apsp Script project with [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)

On this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550548/googlescript-and-aws-sdk), some users have been able to do it with others [AWS services](https://github.com/smithy545/aws-apps-scripts)

### 2. Use the Drive API

If you need Apps Script because you need to handle Google Drive files and send it via email. It'll be better to use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) with [Node JS](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis) and send your emails from your local environment.

Comment: thank you, the thread you posted gives at least a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way to achieve this:

1. AWS \ Privacy
2. AWS \ Role
3. AWS \ Lambda Function
4. AWS \ Add Trigger => API Getaway
5. AWS \ API Getaway
6. Apps Script

All steps are described here:

[Medium\send-emails-with-amazon-aws-ses-from-google-scripts](https://max-makhrov.medium.com/send-emails-with-amazon-aws-ses-from-google-scripts-cf9cf63b170b)

Sample code for Lambda:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: "eu-west-2" });
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  var params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [event.email_to],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: { Data: event.body }, 
      },
    Subject: { Data: event.subject },
    },
    Source: event.email_from,
  };
 
  return ses.sendEmail(params).promise()
};
```

Sample code for Apps-Script:

```
function test_send_ses() {
  var options = {
    method: 'post', 
    payload : JSON.stringify({
      // change
      email_to: "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com",
      body: '<p>Hello from <i>Amazon</i>!</p>',
      subject: 'test mail from Amazon',
      // change
      email_from: 'YOUREMAIL@gmail.com'
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
// change to your url
  var path = 'YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE';
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(path, options)
  Logger.log(result.getResponseCode()); // ➝ 200
  Logger.log(result.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get var aws = require("aws-sdk"); to work.

Comment: It looks like aws-sdk is no longer included by default.

Comment: I've tried changing to Node 14 to make it work and now instead of import error I get "index.handler is undefined or not exported"